# cant use HTML ID in my node.js file electron app with electron-db

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, electron

hello im noob here practicing backend
im try to build simple windwos app using electron and electron-db (https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-db)

but when im trying to save user input in to db row but i cant use input ID as value in insert query

my HTML

```js
const db = require("electron-db");
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const mydb = require("./mydb.js");

// db.createTable("medicine", (succ, msg) => {
//   // succ - boolean, tells if the call is successful
//   if (succ) {
//     console.log(msg);
//   } else {
//     console.log("An error has occured. " + msg);
//   }
// });

let obj = new Object();

obj.name = "Alexius Academia";
obj.property = "Paco, Botolan, Zambales";

if (db.valid("medicine")) {
  db.insertTableContent("medicine", obj, (succ, msg) => {
    // succ - boolean, tells if the call is successful
    console.log("Success: " + succ);
    console.log("Message: " + msg);
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Hello World!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>form</h1>
  <form id="contact-form">
    <label for="name">Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <br><br>
    <label for="property">Porperty</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="property" id="property">
    <br><br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
  </form>
  <script>
    let mim = assad;
  document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
      let property = document.getElementById("property").value;

      console.log(name);
      console.log(property);
      document.getElementById("contact-form").reset();
    });
  </script>
  <script src="mydb.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You said can't save with Id. What error do you get when you try to save or what happens after you submit the form?

Comment: i want to add user input as object but when im trying to add

 let obj = new Object();

obj.name = "Alexius Academia"; (variable here)
obj.property = "Paco, Botolan, Zambales"; (variable here)

its says variable is not defined

Comment: What variable? It's not clear. Please add what you're saying to your original post where it can be formatted. It's difficult to read code in comments because there's really no formatting

Comment: Have you confirmed that the database `medicine.json` file has been created in your Application Data folder? What OS are you testing on; Windows, MacOS or Linux? If it exists, check the contents of the `medicine.json` file. Does it contain your inserted objects similar to the output shown in [Inserting Object/Data to Table](https://github.com/alexiusacademia/electron-db#inserting-objectdata-to-table)?

Comment: yes json file is created and obj.name = "Alexius Academia"; is also added but i want obj.name should be inserted by input im using windows 10

Comment: Ok. So what your asking is how to get your submitted values from `<input type="text" name="name" id="name">` and `<input type="text" name="property" id="property">` into  your `obj` object ready for insertion into your `medicine.json` db?

Comment: yes exactly what i wanted to say.. i know its easy to use with post (expressjs) but i dont know how can i use express so im searching for something that can be usefull without express or creating local server for offline electron app that will work as dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noting that `electron-db` is used in the main thread and you need to get your form data from the render thread to the main thread, you will need to use a process called [Inter-Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc).

To do this safely and securely, you need to become familiar with [Context Isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation).

---

Ok, let's step through this one file at a time...

First off, let's look at the code in your `html` file.

The majority of contents of the `<form>` tag looks good apart from the submit button. Let's change that to `type="button"` as we do not need to natively "submit" the form, only detect when the button is clicked. This also allows us to remove the `event.preventDefault();` line further down in the code.

Now, let's add functionality to the `<script>` tag so it sends the form data off to the main thread. See [ipcRender](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer) for more information on this.

> Note that I have used an IIFE. They can really separate and simplify you code when you have the need to 'instantiate' things. See [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) for more information.

`index.html` (render thread)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Hello World!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>form</h1>

  <form id="contact-form">
    <label for="name">Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <br><br>
    <label for="property">Property</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="property" id="property">
    <br><br><br>
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <script>
    // IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).
    (function() => {
        let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        let property = document.getElementById('property').value;

        document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener('click', submit(name, property))
})();

    // Send the form data back to the main thread.
    function submit(name, property) {
        window.ipcRender.send('contactForm:addData', {
            "name": name,
            "property": property
        });

        // Reset the form (if needed).
        document.getElementById('contact-form').reset();
    }
  </script>

  <script src="mydb.js"></script>
</body>
```

---

The 'glue' that will allow your whitelisted channels to communicate between the main and render threads is call the `preload` script. It is called during the construction of your window. Here we add a 'channel name' to identify it, which in turn will allow it to pass through.

> Notice that I used a `name:function` format so it clearly defines the channel. Useful when you have a lot of channels.

`preload.js` (main thread)

```js
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [
            'contactForm:addData'
        ],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': []
    }
};

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

---

Lastly, within your file in the main thread where you are doing all your work, you need to keep and ear out for a broadcast on that IPC channel.

First, let's add the Electron module `ipcMain` along with the others.

Then, using an IIFE, keep an ear out for a broadcast on that channel. If the channel is called, call the `addContactData` function with the communicated `data` object to insertion into the db.

(main thread)

```js
const db = require("electron-db");
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require("electron");
const mydb = require("./mydb.js");

// IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)
(function() => {
    ipcMain.on('contactForm:addData', (event, data) => { addContactData(data); });
})();

// db.createTable("medicine", (succ, msg) => {
//   // succ - boolean, tells if the call is successful
//   if (succ) {
//     console.log(msg);
//   } else {
//     console.log("An error has occured. " + msg);
//   }
// });

// let obj = new Object();
// obj.name = "Alexius Academia";
// obj.property = "Paco, Botolan, Zambales";

function addContactData(data) {
    if (db.valid("medicine")) {
        db.insertTableContent("medicine", data, (succ, msg) => {
        // succ - boolean, tells if the call is successful
        console.log("Success: " + succ);
        console.log("Message: " + msg);
    });
}
```